# How to remove open icon from plank

Tags: desktop, release-hera

I have seen how to remove the plank icon from the dock, but I don't really know how the syntax of this works and therefore don't know how to replicate it to something else. I recently installed Desktop Folder from the App Store since it adds features of MacOS (which I have come from) but I don't want the icon to always be there. Does anyone know how to help? Thanks in advance!w

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most of the applications can be removed from the Dock by just click and drag outside of the Dock, but for some of them this do not work. Usualy when you right click (or tap with two fingers if you use a trackpad) over any icon on the dock - there is an option that says **keep in Dock**. Uncheck it and this should remove the app or folder from the Dock.

If none of these works, open your files manager, Show hidden files with right click inside the right panel, navigate to you home folder > ~/.config/plank/dock1/launchers and delete the corresponding .dockitem file.